# Why does this callback with a timeout fails to return?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

```
function one(num, callback) {
  return callback(num);
};

function two(num) {
  // return num + 99; << this works
  setTimeout(function() { return num + 99; }, 1000); // << this doesn't
};

console.log(one(55, two));
```

The result of return within a setTimeout is undefined. I can kinda see why it's happening but I don't know how to avoid it.

I've got some functions that I'm `require`ing in node.js, and I want to pass a redis object to them to fetch/set some data, which will likely replicate this scenario if I end up using callbacks of some sort.

Is there a way to return that value?

Comment: The `two` function is asynchronous and isn't returning anything anyways...The `return num + 99;` you have returns from that anonymous function, which is pointless

Comment: Because it is asynchronous. That is how it works. function two returns immediately and then a second later the return num + 99 runs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it sounds like you understand what is happening, but are just not clear on how to deal with it?

You know that `two` cannot return. And it becomes clear that if `two` cannot return, then `one` cannot return either.

So all that is left to do is embrace it, and be asynchronous all the way down the stack:

```
function one(num, doWork, callback) {
  doWork(num, callback);
};

function two(num, callback) {
  setTimeout(function() { callback(num + 99); }, 1000);
};

one(55, two, function (result) { console.log(result); });
```

So `return` becomes `callback` all the way down. Notice how many Node APIs take the form:

```
action(args, function (errorMessage, successMessage) {});
```

Even when they are synchronous. This lets them work easily with the asynchronous APIs.

There are other cool patterns to help you deal with this when it gets cumbersome. I really like promises for when asynchronous stuff starts getting crazy:

https://github.com/kriskowal/q

Comment: You're the hero gotham needs, but doesn't deserve

Answer (score 5):

It is the internals of `setTimeout()` that is calling your anonymous function `function() { return num + 99; }` and thus the return value from that function goes inside of `setTimeout()` where it is ignored.

The `two()` function does not have a return value, so when `one()` returns the return value from calling `two()`, that return value is `undefined`.

Notice in here that there is no return value inside the `two()` function body:

```
function two(num) {
  // return num + 99; << this works
  setTimeout(function() { return num + 99; }, 1000); // << this doesn't
};
```

The `return` statement inside the anonymous callback passed to `setTimeout()` executes some time later after `two()` has finished execution so it has nothing to do with the return value from `two()`.

Comment: Perhaps elaborate on the futility of the return inside the anonymous function?

Comment: @mplungjan - is that not what my first and last sentence does?